# Creating a shared_ptr from an allocator using typedefs?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, allocator

I have some code that I am retrofitting to use an `allocator` instead of `operator new` and `operator delete` directly.  One part of this code's public interface is to return not a bald pointer but a `shared_ptr` (being constructed from the bald pointer wandering out of `new`.)

I see in the public contract for an allocator several typedefs named `pointer`, `const_reference`, etc.  The idea is instead of referring to types `T *` directly, I might use `pointer`, allowing an allocator author to slip in something other than a C pointer.

But I am in turn wrapping the normal pointer in a smart pointer, which wants an honest C pointer (I think.)  If I attempt to change my code over to using the allocator's typedefs, will I run into trouble?  I haven't tried yet (as there is a bit of leg work to do just to try) so I'm asking first..

**EDIT:** Here's the some of code I want to alter (I didn't include the first time, as it isn't very friendly.)

```
template<typename Injector, typename Iface, typename Allocator, typename Impl, typename A1>
class New<Injector, Iface, Allocator, Impl, Impl(A1)>: public Binding<Injector> {
public:
  static Impl * provide(Injector const & injector) {
    SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<A1> a1(injector.template provide<A1>());

    return initializer(injector).template construct<Impl, SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<A1> >(a1);
  }

  static void dispose(Injector const & injector, Iface * iface) {
    Impl * impl = static_cast<Impl *>(iface);
    initializer(injector).destroy(impl);
  }
};

// Elsewhere

template<typename Iface>
SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<Iface> provide() const {
  Iface * provided = provideFromBinding<Iface>(
    Module::template bindings<Injector_> );

  SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<Iface> smartPointer;
  smartPointer.reset(provided, deleter);
  return smartPointer;
}
```

In particular, the `construct` and `destroy` template methods called on the result of the `initializer(injector)` expression currently embed direct uses of `new` and `delete`.  I'd like it to use the `Allocator` instead, and switch them to placement new / explicit destruction, to make something like

```
template<typename Injector, typename Iface, typename Allocator, typename Impl, typename A1>
class New<Injector, Iface, Allocator, Impl, Impl(A1)>: public Binding<Injector> {
public:
  static Impl * provide(Injector const & injector) {
    SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<A1> a1(injector.template provide<A1>());

    Allocator allocator;
    Impl * impl = allocator.allocate(sizeof(Impl));
    initializer(injector).template construct<Impl, SAUCE_SHARED_PTR<A1> >(impl, a1);
    return impl;
  }

  static void dispose(Injector const & injector, Iface * iface) {
    Allocator allocator;
    Impl * impl = static_cast<Impl *>(iface);
    initializer(injector).destroy(impl);
    allocator.deallocate(impl, sizeof(Impl));
  }
};
```

The question is, should I try to honor the allocator's typedefs?  It seems like I ought to be or else I'm not using the allocator correctly (never mind that pragmatically speaking nearly all of them will have the "boring" typedef values.)

I can certainly jigger it to return `Allocator::pointer` instead of `Impl *`, up until I attempt to shove it into a `shared_ptr`.  And maybe it just works there too?  That is my question.  Perhaps someone more familiar with the standard than me could say something like "So long as `Allocator::pointer` quacks like a `operator*` and you register a custom deleter, you'll be fine."

**EDIT:** @bdonlan raises the excellent point that a `shared_ptr` is templated on what would be `Allocator::value_type`, and not `Allocator::pointer`.  Instead, it presumably holds a `Allocator::value_type *` internally.  This seems to answer the question, except an allocator author might choose to implement `operator Allocator::value_type *` on their `Allocator::pointer` in such a way that, even when using the converted value, it "all works out" according to some concretely-stated semantic.

**Does the standard require allocator authors to do this?**

**EDIT:** See [related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434737/requirements-on-standard-library-allocator-pointer-types)

Comment: Why can't Allocator::pointer _be_ a regular pointer, just with a custom deleter?

Comment: I don't control the choice of Allocator.  The idea is some client of this code would be free to choose its own.  In truth, you're right: the common implementations define it exactly that way.

Comment: I think you're thinking about this too much.  There are times when adding too many layers and indirections can do little other than to obfuscate code, and what you're proposing smells like this.  There's something to be said for simple.

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful.

Comment: @phs - I could say the same thing about your question.  How is it "helpful" to do what you are proposing compared to a more standard approach that might make more sense?  To add extra pointers for fun?  To generate less efficient machine code?  (`shared_ptr` is not free.)  To write unreadable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shared_ptr` (and the other TR1 smart pointers) are defined (ie, take template parameters) in terms of the element type, *not* the pointer type. As such, if you are using `shared_ptr`, you cannot substitute your own pointer representation; nor does it make sense to do so in most cases.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  There's no way to mask the `*` in the types in `shared_ptr`.  I'll just have to document the restriction.

Comment: Although you can probably implement most of what you want using the proxy pattern.

Comment: Actually, there's no reason `Allocator::pointer` couldn't implement `operator Allocator::value_type *`.

Comment: Sure, but that's equivalent to being a regular pointer, for most purposes. If you want to be all language-lawyery about it, though, say something like "`Allocator::pointer` shall be convertible to `Allocator::value_type *`" in your docs

Comment: That's what I'll do, unless it's already required by the standard (in which case it goes unsaid.)  Does anyone know?

Comment: Nowhere in sections 20.6.6 to 20.6.9 do I see any reference to constraints on an allocator's choice of `pointer` and related typedefs.

Comment: @phs, I think that would be a different question - feel free to ask it, just not in a comment :)